# Math.Round Returns Incorrect Result

Tags: c#

In below simple code giving me different result for Math.Round. I am missing anything ?

```
public static void Main()
        {
                 double amt = 511.555;
                 double round = Math.Round(amt, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                 Console.WriteLine(round); 
                 //Returns 511.56
                 amt = 512.555;
                 round = Math.Round(amt, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                 Console.WriteLine(round); 
                //Returns 512.55
               Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Check the results of `(511.555).ToString("G17")` and `(512.555).ToString("G17")`.

Comment: This is directly answered on the msdn page for Math.Round for doubles. See section "Note to callers" on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_System_MidpointRounding_

Comment: Also, if you're rounding for display purposes, be aware that the default formatting already does "the right thing" (for certain values of "right"): `(511.555).ToString("0.00") == "511.56"`, `(512.555).ToString("0.00") == "512.56"`.

Comment: You might also want to switch over to `decimal` is you need better precision.